when i change from one network to another when i am in a call i am unable to connect back to the stream and session is ending any solution for this
i am using connectycube for videochat
i tried to change network and see if i can still continue call
after initiating the call i tried to change the network from wi-fi to the mobile-data when i do that the session is ending with out reconnecting i want to reconnect to the session and continue the call after changing the network any help please
i tried every internal function that is in their code nothing worked is there any method reconnects the stream when i change the network connection

This is expected behavior for our "connectycube" and "react-native-connectycube" SDKs.
Previously there was no solution, but now some tools can help solve this problem. We need to do research and test. We will update you soon.
What SDK do you use, for what platforms, and for what version? Do you use video conferencing or video calling

i use video calling

The correct and recommended way for an application to handle all such cases with lost connection is to trigger an ICE restart when the connection state goes to either FAILED or DISCONNECTED for an extended period of time (e.g. > 30 seconds).
How to work with ICE restart:

disable the call termination logic after the network is disconnected for > 30 seconds by increasing the videochat.disconnectTimeInterval value to e.g. 5 mins.

  videochat: {
    disconnectTimeInterval: 300,
  }
};

ConnectyCube.init(credentials, appConfig);


define a variable which can track the Internet connection state:

let isOnline = window.navigator.onLine;

window.onoffline = () => {
  isOnline = false;
};

window.ononline = () => {
  isOnline = true;
};


define a function that will perform ICE restart:

  async maybeDoIceRestart(session, userID) {
    try {
      // firstly let's check if we are still connected to chat
      await ConnectyCube.chat.pingWithTimeout();

      // do ICE restart
      if (session.canInitiateIceRestart(userID)) {
        session.iceRestart(userID);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);

      // chat ping request has timed out,
      // so need to reconnect to Chat

      await ConnectyCube.chat.disconnect();
      await ConnectyCube.chat.connect({
        userId: currentUser.id,
        password: currentUser.password,
      })

      // do ICE restart
      if (session.canInitiateIceRestart(userID)) {
        session.iceRestart(userID);
      }
    }
  }


define a ConnectyCube.videochat.onSessionConnectionStateChangedListener callback and try to perform ICE restart if not automatic call restoration happened after 30 seconds:

iceRestartTimeout = null;
needIceRestartForUsersIds = [];

ConnectyCube.videochat.onSessionConnectionStateChangedListener = (
  session,
  userID,
  connectionState
) => {
  console.log(
    "[onSessionConnectionStateChangedListener]",
    userID,
    connectionState
  );

  const { DISCONNECTED, FAILED, CONNECTED, CLOSED } =
    ConnectyCube.videochat.SessionConnectionState;

  if (connectionState === DISCONNECTED || connectionState === FAILED) {
    iceRestartTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // Connection not restored within 30 seconds, trying ICE restart...
      if (isOnline) {
        maybeDoIceRestart(session, userID);
      } else {
        // Skip ICE restart, no Internet connection
        this.needIceRestartForUsersIds.push(userID);
      }
    }, 30000);
  } else if (connectionState === CONNECTED) {
    clearTimeout(iceRestartTimeout);
    iceRestartTimeout = null;

    needIceRestartForUsersIds = [];
  } else if (connectionState === CLOSED) {
    needIceRestartForUsersIds = [];
  }
};


In a case a user got working Internet connection later, do ICE restart there:

window.ononline = () => {
  if (!isOnline) {
    if (session && needIceRestartForUsersIds.length > 0) {
      for (let userID of needIceRestartForUsersIds) {
        maybeDoIceRestart(session, userID);
      }
    }
  }
  isOnline = true;
};

The following is the source of this info.
New SDK 3.32.0 https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-js-sdk-releases/releases/tag/3.32.0
Documentation

https://developers.connectycube.com/js/videocalling/#tackling-network-changes
https://developers.connectycube.com/reactnative/videocalling/#tackling-network-changes

for reference - PR with new SDK integration into Web p2p voice & video calling sample https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-web-samples/pull/285

+1 but the reviewers might delete this answer anyway unless you copy/paste some of the essential information from your links into this answer to preserve continuity. I'm hoping for the best outcome.

Please rephrase a little to avoid the "link only" inpression. Also leave the judging of whether the question is resolved to the OP please (though even from the OP, that is practically irrelevant for StackOverflow concepts).  Also give a summary of why the other links are here and if necessary what technical details they contribute. I will paste the standard comment for link-only answers below, for your reference why I propose these changes.

Yuliia Khomenko, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: You need to provide at least a technical summary of how the problem is solved, so that it can be reproduced even without the link. It is not enough to advertise what it achieves. Also please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Maybe phrase like "You need to use an updated SDK, because ...." Note how that states the solutions and explains why it helps, instead of just mentioning something like in your phrasing.

thanks for the feedback @Yunnosch
I've added all the information in my comment

thanks @karelI've added all the info

Thanks for the quite decent edits. However, please take the [tour], it might help you to understand a few missed concepts, e.g. the difference between  a comment and an answer and why an answer should not contain any opinion on whether or not it resolves the problem and the necessity of crediting content from elsewhere. I did a few corresponding edits.
